# Google Cloud SQL Admin API backing up along with Stored Procedures and Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

By exploring the [API libraries](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/) provided by GCP I see we can create on-demand backups.

But in MySQL we can backup Stored Procedures and functions using --trigger flag in the mysqldump command. I don't find this flag as an argument in the API.

And [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#mysqldump) says we cannot backup triggers using gcloud or cURL and recommended to use mysqldump against in the instance itself.

I wanted to know if still there is a way we can dump along with procedures Programmatically, Where we can achieve complete backups of the DB. I do it periodically using Cloud Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research and exploration of GCP, there is no way you can get a complete backup of the Cloud SQL using any of the GCP features/apps.

The only way is running `mysqldump` against the Cloud SQL instance, means we can run this command against the instance having the connection access.

I created a simple NodeJS server with an endpoint which performs this mysqldump operation.

***Cloud Scheduler > An Endpoint on a server > Dump the whole data using whatever the flags > Store it in Google Cloud Storage.***

Answer (score 0):

Dumping everything is not possible using just GCP interface or APIs, but it is with mysqldump run directly on the instance +  scripting/scheduling , which is basically what you said.

In addition,  in [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html) of the MySQL docs, it is stated that mysqldump exports:
Stored Procedures and Functions depending on the option `--routines`.
Triggers for tables depending on the option `--triggers`.
So you have a bit more control for your dumping than just `--triggers`.

And, as a side note, consider that, if you are going to import those dumps into CloudSQL again (which I understand is what you do, as you are backing up) then you can't export them with Stored Procedures, Functions or Triggers. CloudSQL is unable to import dumps with any of these elements, as [the docs say](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv#sqldump).

Comment: Cloud SQL import/export are indeed very limited as you describe - which makes working with it really tricky (you can easily end up with a circular dependency of schema, triggers and functions). Depending on use-case, you may be better off doing an import from an instance that can access the database, rather than using the 'import' API feature.